# Angular Mat Table show same column two times but error "Duplicate column definition name provided"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

What is the simplest way, to duplicate a column side-by-side with identical data?
I don't like to modify the JSON data and use two different matColumnDef keys for the same data, this would be overkill.

data:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'}
];
```

attempt to duplicate:

```
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Duplicate Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Error message:

```
Duplicate column definition name provided: "name".
```

The error message is only visible in stackblitz with "open in new tab" in the top right and then using the browser console.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jska2p?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Is there a nice trick to bypass the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that, because the system will got confused
in HTML, the page need the variable displayedColumns, so its on the loop,

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

if you want need the same data, you just add column in the array displayedColumns, just like this:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'duplicateName', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

in HTML:

```
  <!-- Duplicate Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="duplicateName">  //Just change in here
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
```